# If I auto forward emails to another Gmail address can that account reply to the original sender using my email address?

Tags: gmail, email-forwarding

In Gmail, is Automatic Forwarding safe?  If I auto forward a message to another Gmail account, can that account reply as if they were the original intended recipient? Are there any dangers?

- For Example - 'Account-One'( A Gmail Account ), receives an email, and because Automatic Forwarding for all email is set On, it is forwarded to 'Account-Two'( A Gmail Account ) which then replies to it, and, the 'Original Sender' of the email receives the reply which shows that the reply has been sent from 'Account-One'( A Gmail Account ) .
- Are there risks associated with using Automatic-Forwarding from a Gmail account to another Gmail account, or from a Gmail account to a Non Gmail account?
- The reason I would want to do this, is because I have a primary Gmail account ('Account-One'), which I only use from a SIM card,  and I also have a secondary Gmail account('Account-Two') which I use from a very very public WIFI network, so there is a greater chance of 'Account-Two' being hacked.

Comment: Hi. _the very original sender of the email receives the reply which shows that the reply has been sent from 'Account-One'_ Have you actually tested this?

Comment: yes, obviously that is what I should do, however, since I don't know all the possible options / settings for 'Automatic Forwarding' I could probably not test it fully and completely to fully and correctly answer this question - Obviously, logic would indicate that this feature would be safe, however........................

Answer (score 0):

By default, if YOU forward an email from Sender X from your Gmail ONE to your Gmail TWO, the reply from Gmail TWO to Sender X will show that it came from Gmail TWO, not Gmail ONE, and there will be a trail of information in the headers showing the history of the message.

You shouldn't feel stupid.  The questions you are asking are very general and difficult to answer precisely in a comprehensive way.

There are people trying to get into your stuff online and you are (as we all are) the weak link.

If you have time to invest you would be well served to invest the energy learning how to protect your safety and security online when surfing public networks and using other people's computers.   As you identified that is the danger and learning to protect your data, better secure your accounts and internet traffic would address the most obvious risks.

For example, do you have a good password manager with randomized passwords and 2FA?  Are your Google passwords complex and unrelated?
Do you reuse passwords and variations on passwords on multiple sites?

Hope that helps :-)